# If I do VS If I did

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Do these sentences mean exactly the same thing? If yes, why does (a) use the present tense and (b) the past?

(a) IF I WIN the lottery, I WILL buy a big house.

(b) IF I WON the lottery, I WOULD BUY a big house.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

***Timing*** is everything.

In the first instance, there is a real possibility of winning the lottery. The speaker has already purchased a lottery ticket and is awaiting the draw.

In the second instance, the speaker is fantasizing about winning the lottery someday.

Comment: There is never a real possibility to win ;))) If there were, he should use "When I win"...

Comment: Can you please give me some suggested reading for the second case.

Comment: @ᚔZenOutᚔ I cannot. However, if "spoken" by the protagonist, I can easily imagine it introducing most any episode of a typical American television situation comedy.